Patching RavenDb documents using a Dictionary<string, object>
I'm trying to patch a single/multiple documents (identified by their id) with that I receive in a Dictionary<string, object>. The key of the dictionary is the path to the document property to update, and it may even be a subpath.
So if my document looks like this:
public class MyDoc
{
    public string StringProp {get; set;}
    public bool? BoolProp {get; set;}
    public int? IntProp {get; set;}
    public SubDocument SubProp {get; set;}
}

public class SubDocument
{
    public string StringProp {get; set;}
}

So an example Dictionary may be:
new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
    {"StringProp", "hello" },
    {"BoolProp", true },
    {"SubProp.StringProp", "subprop value" },
}

I know how to fetch the document(s), apply the dictionary to it and save the document(s), but I'm looking for a way that doesn't require the extraction of the documents I want to modify.
I'm guessing it would go something along these lines:
 var operation = store
    .Operations
    .Send(new PatchByQueryOperation(new IndexQuery
    {
        QueryParameters = new Parameters
        {
            {"ids", new[] {"orders/1-A", "companies/1-A"}}
        },
         Query = @"from @all_docs as d where id() in ($ids)
          update
          {
              d.StringProp = 'hello';
              d.BoolProp = true;
              d.SubProp.StringProp = 'subprop value';
          }"
}));

And what if SubProp doesn't exist on a document or if I'd like to assign the entire SubProp rather than just fill a property on a subdocument?

Regarding your second Question about:
"assigning the entire SubProp rather than just filling a property on a subdocument"
The following will work:
var subObject = new SubDocument() {StringProp = "new sub text"};

var operation = store.Operations.Send(new PatchByQueryOperation(new IndexQuery
{
    QueryParameters = new Parameters
    {
        { "ids", new[] {"myDocs/1", "companies/1-A"} },
        { "subObject", subObject }
    },
    Query = @"from @all_docs as d where id() in ($ids)
                  update
                  {
                      d.StringProp = 'hello';
                      d.BoolProp = false;
                      d.SubProp = ($subObject);
                  }"
}));


Regarding your first Question about:
"what if SubProp doesn't exist on a document"
1.
Patching with d.SubProp = 'value1' when SubProp doesn't exist,  will succeed and property SubProp will be created with value1.
2.
Patching with d.SubProp.StringProp = 'value2' will only succeed if property SubProp is an object type (not a string).

If you need to patch only a single document, then you don't have to use set-based patching. You can use single-document patching.
Single-document patching is explained by these articles:
(Note: the Node.js article is currently more organized and detailed, the C# article is TBD, however logic behind is the same)
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/nodejs/client-api/operations/patching/single-document
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document

WRT the second part of your answer. In my original question you can see the dictionary that holds what I want to patch. This is the same for single document and multi-document patching. The Patch API on session.Advanced is typed, so it requires two type parameters I don't have in my dictionary (and I can only get a Type, not the T syntax). So, I'd need to be able to build an expression for 'set property X to Y' somehow. Something like PatchGeneric<T>(string entityId, string propertyPath, object value).
